# @Order annotation vs FilterRegistrationBean.setOrder vs addFilterBefore/addFilterAfter in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter, configuration

I am adding filters in my application and I want to set the order of call for these filters. I can see three ways but I don't know if they're at all related?

**Using `@Order` annotation:**

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class SampleFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
   ...   
}
```

**Register the filter via config:**

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<SampleFilter> perfFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<SampleFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registration.setFilter(new SampleFilter());
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

**Via WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:**

```
public class SampleConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private SampleFilter sampleFilter;

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      ...
      http.addFilterBefore(this.sampleFilter, SampleFilterTwo.class);
   }

}
```

Comment: 1 and 2 are more or less the same, 3 is not. The first 2 add the filter to the regular filter chain, the last one adds it to the so called filter security chain which is basically a `Filter` acting as a filter chain, this is done/needed so spring security has more control over the order and lifecycle of the filters.

Comment: @m-deinum where does the filter security chain fall when it comes to ordering? if I add my regular filter to the filter security chain (like above example), how will that affect the order?

Comment: Say I have CustomFilter1 with @Order(1) and CustomerFilter2 with @Order(2), then I added them in the security filter with addFilterBefore(customFilter2, CustomFilter1.class) which means CustomFilter2 going before CustomFilter1. How would that work?

Comment: The order isn't taken into account or even worse it is registered twice (once in the regular chain and as part of the security chain. Only add things to the security chain that actually are (spring) security related, else make it part of the normal chain.